# application returns 404 error after payumoney successful payment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat7, csrf, payumoney

After payment is done. When payumoney redirects to my application with POST request. I am getting 404 even having request mapping.

URL: [test.payumoney.com/payment/postBackParam.do:23][1]

I tried with the plain form from my application, it is hitting my application. When it comes to request from another site, it is throwing 404 error.

Do I need to change any server setting Where it should accept this kind of request?

REQUEST HEADERS:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/ *;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1075
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=60A54F6DAB5259BAD651EC00C199FCE5
Origin:null
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.167 Safari/537.36
```

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: why your URL looks like this: `URL :[test.payumoney.com/payment/postBackParam.do:23][1]` ? is that the actual request url being attempted?

Comment: just typo mistake:test.payumoney.com/payment/postBackParam.do:23

Comment: is that a valid url?

Comment: Large blocks of code (or, in this case, headers) become much more readable when indented properly. You can just highlight your code block and hit CTRL+k to easily present it in a text box. I also put a space in part of the Accept: line, because it contained /* which was being interpreted as the start of a comment, and graying out all of the text in the box.